# SSH connection stuck in 'Local version string'

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

I am trying to SSH connect from my MacBook to my Ubuntu machine.
I have typed in this command `ssh -p 22 -vvv <username>@<ip>`
The firewall is also disabled in the server side, and typed `systemctl status sshd` to make sure if it is open.

It connects, but does not show the prompt at all.

```
OpenSSH_7.6p1, LibreSSL 2.6.2
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line  48: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 52: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to <ip> port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/sss/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/sss/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/sss/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/sss/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/sss/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/sss/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/sss/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/sss/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6
```

It always seems to get stuck in the last line.

I am testing my MacBook on a different network, but when I try the same command in the same Wifi, it works perfectly.

(I've already tried various stuff in the internet and still does not work) I just started using Ubuntu, so the problem might actually be simple.

Comment: Are you saying the client machine can connect to the server from one network, but the same client machine trying to connect to the same server from another network gets stuck at that point?

Comment: Unless the use of DNS by sshd is disabled in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on the Ubuntu server, it might be trying to find out the name of the system you're connecting from - and if you're in another private network behind a NAT, that is unlikely to succeed. Try adding/uncommenting `UseDNS no` in `sshd_config` and then restarting sshd with `systemctl restart sshd`.

Comment: @telcoM It is already uncommented in the file.

Comment: @rfc2460 Yes, it connects without getting stuck when I'm in the same network.

Comment: @MallowMarsh Same network as what exactly? A packet capture from each end while you are having this problem would definitely help debugging the issue.

Comment: It seems like a duplicate of: https://superuser.com/questions/1374076/what-does-it-mean-if-ssh-hangs-after-connection-established

Comment: My problem was a dropped but not closed remote ssh port connection.

Comment: FWIW, I'm seeing this exact thing. The server (a RasperryPi) creates a reverse tunnel to a server I have on the internet. After some possible (but not proven) corruption issues, I can connect to the RPi without problems from the local network but when I connect via the reverse tunnel it gets stuck here -- for a few minutes, then goes through, then gets stuck, then continues, then gets stuck. Occasionally it's successful.

Comment: Seems to have been resolved in my case by restarting sshd.

Answer (score 1):

I remember facing the same issue when using `UseDNS yes` in my sshd config, try setting it to **no** and hopefully it'll resolve your problem

if your ISP gives IPs without rDNS this usually happens

how to know if your IP has a reverse DNS record? visit [www.whatismyip.com](http://www.whatismyip.com) or similar and take the IP then run `host 1.1.1.1` where 1.1.1.1 is your IP and see if it gives a reply back, if it doesn't like when you `host 11.11.11.11` then your ISP doesn't set rDNS records

```
bashar@bashar-ThinkPad-W520:~$ host 1.1.1.1
1.1.1.1.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer one.one.one.one.

bashar@bashar-ThinkPad-W520:~$ host 11.11.11.11
Host 11.11.11.11.in-addr.arpa. not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

Additionally, you may want to look at `GSSAPIAuthentication no` or test it by adding `-u0` to your ssh command

Comment: Just wanted to note, option `-u0` on `OpenSSH_8.3p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020` tells me "`ssh: unknown option -- u`"

Answer (score 1):

I've stuck with the same problem and I've worked around with this configuration:

[image: Port Forwarding]

The key was setting Guest IP as 0.0.0.0

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by simply doing on the remote machine (Just like you, I had access without VPN but could not access with the VPN):

```sh
sudo systemctl restart ssh.service
```

The hanging of the ssh connection happened several times to me over the past few days and running this command never has failed to solve the problem.